# Получить значения атрибутов разных элементов (jsoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть строка вида:

```
<p class="name"><a href="/level/1/book/22446/sr/1/" class="js-serp-metrika" data-url="/book/22446" data-id="22446" data-type="book">Название</a> <span class="year">2015</span></p>
```

С помощью выражений вида:

```
Elements named = doc.select("p.name > a");

for (Element el : named)
    System.out.println(el.attr("data-url"));
```

получаю значения нужных атрибутов, но как можно получить `text()` класса `year`? Он находится в элементе `р`. Можно ли как-либо объединять селекторы `p.name > a` и `p.name`?

Comment: Пустой ответ ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> но как можно получить `text()` класса `year`?

Например, вот так:

```
Document page = Jsoup.parse("<p class=\"name\"><a href=\"/level/1/book/22446/sr/1/\" class=\"js-serp-metrika\" data-url=\"/book/22446\" data-id=\"22446\" data-type=\"book\">Название</a> <span class=\"year\">2015</span></p>");
Element yearElement = page.select("p.name > span.year").get(0);
System.out.println(yearElement.text());
```

Comment: Теперь осталось только связать el.attr("data-url") и yearElement. Так как они относятся к разным элементам, то, когда строк несколько,

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < named.size(); i++) {           
                System.out.println(named.get(i).attr("data-url") + "  " + named.get(i).text() + "   " + yearElement.get(i).text());
        }        связываются не правильно

Comment: @Tariel, Я отвечал четко на поставленный вопрос, а в нем строка одна.